# Excel VBA: Skip the copied cell in for loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a some data where I have some conditions. If each cell in column B contains words like "and", "or", "and/or", then create a copy of that row and insert it into next row following the copied row.

Currently my data looks like this:
[image]

This is my code:

```
Sub Macro2()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, rowRange As Range
        
    Set rng = Range("B1", Range("B1").End(xlDown))
    
    Dim values As Variant
    Dim Result() As String
    connectorArray = Array("and/or", "or", "and")
    Dim findConnectorWord As String
        
    'Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    'Range("B1", Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Select
    
    For Each cell In rng
        findConnectorWord = FindString(cell.Value, connectorArray)
        If findConnectorWord <> vbNullString Then
            Result() = Split(cell, findConnectorWord)
            Set rowRange = Range("A" & cell.Row, Range("B" & cell.Row).End(xlToRight))
            rowRange.Copy           
            rowRange .Offset(1, 0).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    
            'Logic to skip the next cell

        End If
    Next cell    
End Sub

Function FindString(SearchString As String, arr As Variant) As String
    For Each searchWord In arr
        If InStr(SearchString, searchWord) > 0 Then
            FindString = searchWord
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

The problem that I am having is that once the row is copied and inserted into the next row, the next iteration reads the copied row("Homeowners or Dwelling Fire") and creates another copy. What I would like to do is to skip the cell once the row is copied, inside the if condition and look at Cell B3(Assuming that Umbrella (C) gets pushed down when the new cell is copied over). What's the best possible way to do this?

Comment: Iterate backwards so that you insert after the current line

Comment: use `Do While` loop instead, and increment the row counter by 2 when you copy>>paste a row

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible options for implementing what @freeflow wrote about in his comment:

```
    ...
    Set cell = Range("B1").End(xlDown)  ' start from last cell
    Do Until False
        findConnectorWord = FindString(cell.Value, connectorArray)
        If findConnectorWord <> vbNullString Then
            ...
            Set rowRange = cell.EntireRow
            rowRange.Copy
            rowRange.Offset(1, 0).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If
        If cell.Row = 1 Then Exit Do ' First row? Enough
        Set cell = cell.Offset(-1, 0)   ' Shift up
    Loop
   ...
```

And one more note - when defining values ​​for connectorArray, add spaces to the terms: `" and "` instead of `"and"`. Otherwise, you can duplicate the line with some Brandon or Alexandra